# How to obtain 1 column from a series object pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I originally have 3 columns, timestamp,response_time and type columns, what I need to do is find the mean of response time where all timestamps are same hence I grouped all timestamps together and applied mean function on them. I got the following series which is fine:

```
0     16.949689
1     17.274615
2     16.858884
3     17.025155
4     17.062008
5     16.846885
6     17.172994
7     17.025797
8     17.001974
9     16.924636
10    16.813300
11    17.152066
12    17.291899
13    16.946970
14    16.972884
15    16.871824
16    16.840024
17    17.227682
18    17.288211
19    17.370553
20    17.395759
21    17.449579
22    17.340357
23    17.137308
24    16.981012
25    16.946727
26    16.947073
27    16.830850
28    17.366538
29    17.054468
30    16.823983
31    17.115429
32    16.859003
33    16.919645
34    17.351895
35    16.930233
36    17.025194
37    16.824997
```

And I need to be able to plot column 1 vs column 2, but I am not abel to extract them seperately.

I obtained this column by doing `groupby('timestamp')` and then a `mean()` on that.

The problem I need to solve is how to extract each column of this series? or is there a better way to calculate the mean of 1 column for all same entries of another column?

ORIGINAL DATA :

```
1445544152817,SEND_MSG,123
1445544152817,SEND_MSG,123
1445544152829,SEND_MSG,135
1445544152829,SEND_MSG,135
1445544152830,SEND_MSG,135
1445544152830,GET_QUEUE,12
1445544152830,SEND_MSG,136
1445544152830,SEND_MSG,136
1445544152830,SEND_MSG,136
1445544152831,SEND_MSG,138
1445544152831,SEND_MSG,136
1445544152831,SEND_MSG,137
1445544152831,SEND_MSG,137
1445544152831,SEND_MSG,137
1445544152832,SEND_MSG,138
1445544152832,SEND_MSG,138
1445544152833,SEND_MSG,138
1445544152833,SEND_MSG,139
1445544152834,SEND_MSG,140
1445544152834,SEND_MSG,140
1445544152834,SEND_MSG,140
1445544152835,SEND_MSG,140
1445544152835,SEND_MSG,141
1445544152849,SEND_MSG,155
1445544152849,SEND_MSG,155
1445544152850,GET_QUEUE,21
1445544152850,GET_QUEUE,21
```

For each timestamp I want to find average of response_time and plot,I did that successfully as shown in the series above(first data) but I cannot seperate the timestamp and response_time columns anymore.

Comment: can you post all columns??

Answer (score 2):

A Series always has just one column. The first column you see is the `index`. You can get it by `your_series.index()`. If you want the timestamp to become a data column again, and not an index you can use the `as_index` keyword in groupby:

```
df.groupby('timestamp', as_index = False).mean()
```

Or use `your_series.reset_index()`.

Answer (score 0):

if its a series, you can directly use:

```
your_series.mean()
```

you can extract the column by:

```
df['column_name']
```

then you can apply `mean()` to the series:

```
df['column_name'].mean()
```

Comment: it says key error, it does recognize 'response_time' as a column name of the series

Comment: is it a series or dataframe??

Comment: when you do a groupby and a mean on that dont you get a series?Thats my problem